# Contrapositive of this statement

Tags: logic

Suppose $∀x ∈ R, ∃y ∈ R$, s.t. $∀z ∈ R.$
Consider the following statement:

$$z > y \implies z > x + y $$

The contrapositive of this statement is:

$$z ≤ x+y \implies z ≤ y$$

with the same quantifiers as the first statement.

It seems pretty obvious that since the premise, i.e $z ≤ x+y$  is always false (you cant have one value fixed for y that justifies the inequality for all values of x and z)the statement should be vacuously true.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: YES; The *contrapositive* of : $(z > y \to z > x + y)$ is : $(z \le x + y \to z \le y)$. Thus, being equivalent, the first formula is equivalent to : $∀x∃y∀z(z \le x + y \to z \le y)$.

Comment: But the actual answer is that the original statement is false...
In the book the author negates the statement- concludes the negated statement as true and hence the original is false.

Comment: I've only said that they are *equivalent*, i.e. both *ture* or both *false* ...

Comment: Your problem seems to be to confuse $Q(\overline{x})[\phi(\overline{x})\Rightarrow\chi(\overline{x})]$ (where $\overline{x}$ is a variable vector, $Q$ a quantifier sequence which bounds all variables in $\overline{x}$ and $\phi$ resp. $\chi$ formulas with free variables among $\overline{x}$) with $Q(\overline{x})[\phi(\overline{x})]\Rightarrow Q(\overline{x})[\chi(\overline{x})]$, i.e. when you evaluate the if part of your statement then all variables are already fixed by the quantifiers and the premise is *not* automatically false.

Comment: Im still a bit confused why the variables are fixed if it says for all values of x and z.

Comment: Let's assume a simpler case, the statement $\forall x.(x>0\Rightarrow x<0)$ is false but $\forall x.x>0$ is false either, still you can't argue the way you did (if I didn't misunderstood you) that $x>0\Rightarrow x<0$ must be always true then.

Comment: WOW! That was brilliantly explained. Thank you so much fweth!!

Answer (score 2):

In order to "falsify" :

> $∀x∃y∀z(z≤x+y → z≤y)$

we have to find a suitable value for $x$ such that $∃y∀z(z≤x+y → z≤y)$ is *false*.

Let's try with $z-y$ as value for $x$. Thus, we have to show that :

> $∃y∀z(z≤z → z≤y)$

is *false*. While $z \le z$ is trivially true, we cannot find a value for $y$ such that $z \le y$ is **always** true.

---

Thus, "going backwards" we have that :

> $∀y∃z(z ≤ z \land z > y)$

is *satisfied* (it is enough to choose $y+1$ as value for $z$).

An thus :

> $∃x∀y∃z(z ≤ x+y \land z > y)$

is also satisfied with $1$ as value for $x$ (if $z=y+1$, then $z \le x+y$ for some $x$).

But the *negation* of he last formula is :

> $$\lnot ∃x∀y∃z(z ≤ x+y \land z > y) \equiv ∀x∃y∀z \lnot (z ≤ x+y \land z > y) \equiv$$
>
> $$\equiv ∀x∃y∀z (z ≤ x+y \to z \le y).$$